# Locust POST Request working in one format and not another

Tags: json, post, locust

In our Locust scripts, we have a standardized format that we follow with self.client.post. In this format, I'm unable to get this post request to work:

```
loginCreds = {"data":{"email":"email@email.net","password":"password"}}
string=json.dumps(loginCreds)
with self.client.post("/apis/authentication/login", name=f'login-{self.client.userrole} || /apis/authentication/login', data=string, headers=auth_headers, catch_response=True) as r:
```

I tried using a different format, which does work for the same request:

```
loginCreds = {"data":{"email":"email@email.net","password":"password"}}
string=json.dumps(loginCreds)
requests.post("https://xyz.xyz.com//apis/authentication/login", data=string, headers=auth_headers)
```

In the case of the first format, the full URL is being passed from the headers, and I can see it is trying to hit the correct address. In the second format, it wasn't able to pick it up from the headers and I added it. But this doesn't seem to be where the issue lies.

The error I'm receiving is:
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

I think it has to do with how the loginCreds data is being passed. Is there anything we should be doing differently in the self.client.post format to get it to pass correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I'd try is put the full URL in the `self.client.post` instead just the route. Do it just like you did for the `requests.post`.

You can also get the [final request info](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#lower-lower-level-classes) from [the response object](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.request). Use that to compare what was actually sent.

```
loginCreds = {"data":{"email":"email@email.net","password":"password"}}
string=json.dumps(loginCreds)
r = self.client.post("/apis/authentication/login", name=f'login-{self.client.userrole} || /apis/authentication/login', data=string, headers=auth_headers)
print(r.request.url)
print(r.request.headers)
print(r.request.body)
```

Comment: Adding full URL doesn't change anything. But your tip to print the final request info, I've been trying to search how to do that with my formatting for days. What you've shared is working for me. This will make it much easier to troubleshoot the issue, thanks for that.

Comment: It seems my problem is in an auto-generated cookie from the preceding API, so not at all what I was trying to tweak to get it working. Thanks again for the Request printing tip